# Need help searching entire workbook and not just a single sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need help modifying the code below to look through the entire workbook searching for "$" instead of just one. I would love it if it could just search for CGYSR-"##". I have had help putting the code together as I am new to VBA

Here is the code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub FindPriceTagInformation()
Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim MyArr As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rcount As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim NewSh As Worksheet


With Application
.ScreenUpdating = False
.EnableEvents = False
End With

'Fill in the search Value
MyArr = Array("$")

Set NewSh = Sheets("Sheet2")

With Sheets("CGYSR-3").Range("A1:ZZ300")

Rcount = 0

For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)


Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
LookIn:=xlValues, _
LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False)

If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
FirstAddress = Rng.Address
Do
Rcount = Rcount + 1
NewSh.Cells(Rcount, 3).Value = Rng.Value

NewSh.Cells(Rcount, 2).Value = Rng.Offset(-3, 0).Value
NewSh.Cells(Rcount, 1).Value = Rng.Offset(-5, 0).Value

Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
End If
Next I
End With

With Application
.ScreenUpdating = True
.EnableEvents = True
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Search for **search for CGYSR-"##"** or search for "$"? Looking to your code, should we deduce that you need to search not **in** all worksheet, only in the ones being named according to that pattern? I mean "CGYSR-01", "CGYSR-02", "CGYSR-11",  and so on?

Comment: @FaneDuru Correct, I am trying to search for "$" in all CGYSR-##, or if thats not possible in all sheets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next adapted code:

```
Sub FindPriceTagInformation()
 Dim FirstAddress As String, MyArr, Rng As Range, Rcount As Long, I As Long
 Dim ws As Worksheet, NewSh As Worksheet

 With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
 End With

 'Fill in the search Value
 MyArr = Array("$")
 Set NewSh = Sheets("Sheet2")
 Rcount = 0
 For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If left(ws.Name, 6) = "CGYSR-" Then
       With ws.Range("A1:ZZ300")
           For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)
               Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                   After:=.cells(.cells.count), _
                   LookIn:=xlValues, _
                   LookAt:=xlPart, _
                   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                   SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                   MatchCase:=False)
               
               If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                   FirstAddress = Rng.Address
                   Do
                       Rcount = Rcount + 1
                       NewSh.cells(Rcount, 3).value = Rng.value
                       
                       NewSh.cells(Rcount, 2).value = Rng.Offset(-3, 0).value
                       NewSh.cells(Rcount, 1).value = Rng.Offset(-5, 0).value
                       
                       Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
                   Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
               End If
           Next I
       End With
    End If
 Next ws
 With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
 End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Oh perfect.  Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

### Searching in Worksheets

- In the workbook containing this code (`ThisWorkbook`), loops through each worksheet trying to identify the ones whose name starts with a given string (`CGYSR-`). Then it searches for a `$` identifying cells with prices and retrieves these cell's values and the values of two other associated cells (3 and 5 cells above) and writes them to a row in another worksheet (`Sheet2`).

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FindPriceTagInformation()
    
    Const swsNameBegin As String = "CGYSR-"
    Const srgAddress As String = "A1:ZZ300"
    Const dwsName As String = "Sheet2"
    
    Dim SearchStrings As Variant: SearchStrings = Array("$")
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    ' Destination Worksheet
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dwsName)
    
    ' You do it once here, so you don't have to do it many times in the loops.
    Dim sCellsCount As Long: sCellsCount = dws.Range(srgAddress).Cells.Count
    Dim npLen As String: npLen = Len(swsNameBegin)
    Dim ssLower As Long: ssLower = LBound(SearchStrings)
    Dim ssUpper As Long: ssUpper = UBound(SearchStrings)
    
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    
    Dim sws As Worksheet ' Source Worksheet
    Dim srg As Range ' Srouce Range
    Dim sfCell As Range ' Source Found Cell
    Dim slCell As Range ' Source Last Cell
    Dim dr As Long ' Current Destination Row
    Dim ss As Long ' Current Search String
    Dim FirstAddress As String
    
    For Each sws In wb.Worksheets
        ' A 'begins-with' ('Left') comparison where 'StrComp' will return 0 if
        ' the strings are equal. Combined with 'vbTextCompare', it will
        ' ignore case i.e. 'CG=cg'.
        If StrComp(Left(sws.Name, npLen), swsNameBegin, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            Set srg = sws.Range(srgAddress)
            Set slCell = srg.Cells(sCellsCount) ' the same for all strings
            For ss = ssLower To ssUpper
                Set sfCell = srg.Find( _
                    What:=SearchStrings(ss), _
                    After:=slCell, _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlPart, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows)
                If Not sfCell Is Nothing Then ' string was found
                    FirstAddress = sfCell.Address ' to prevent an endless loop
                    Do
                        ' Write to the Destination Worksheet.
                        dr = dr + 1
                        dws.Cells(dr, 3).Value = sfCell.Value
                        dws.Cells(dr, 2).Value = sfCell.Offset(-3, 0).Value
                        dws.Cells(dr, 1).Value = sfCell.Offset(-5, 0).Value
                        ' Find next string.
                        Set sfCell = srg.FindNext(sfCell)
                    ' Note that in this case, 'sfCell' will never ever
                    ' be 'Nothing' once it's 'something'. The 'Find' method
                    ' doesn't 'know' where it found the first: it just finds
                    ' the next even if it's the same (it goes round and round)
                    ' i.e. if there is one cell to find,
                    ' it will find it 'forever'.
                    ' That's the reason behind comparing with the first address.
                    Loop While sfCell.Address <> FirstAddress
                    Set sfCell = Nothing ' reset for the next string
                'Else ' string was not found
                End If
            Next ss
        End If
    Next sws
    
    With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    'Inform: useful for short and long operations.
    MsgBox "Retrieved price tag information.", vbInformation

End Sub
```